# PHP mailer - problems with some email address not receiving them

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem with certain members not receiving their emails. These include aol.com and hotmail.co.uk.

I have sent identical emails using (1) PHPmailer and (2) Thunderbird, and find certain things added in the PHP one, but they do not appear anywhere in the PHPmailer.php file

For example "X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1003:class.phpmailer.php"

Where does that come from and is that the reason emails are failing?

Or is it the fact that there is more than one address in the To: line - should one loop and send each one separately rather than sending them all in one PHPmail - only problems then are that with attachments, this would jam up the bandwidth.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the `X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1003:class.phpmailer.php` is because phpmailer is adding it's own signature to all e-mails sent.

to fix that you should:
- update phpmailer to the newest version
- send mail via SMTP
- as last resort, hardcode change the X-PHP-Originating-Script to say something like "thunderbird"

The e-mails are definitely not passing through firewall thus landing in spam.